# Run .sh file terminal

Tags: shell, sh

I ran below command line from a terminal and it works:

```
sftp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@host
put csv_file
put manifest_file
```

I want to automatically run this so I created a .sh file that looks like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
sftp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@host
put csv_file
put manifest_file
```

and save it as run.sh. I ran it like below:

```
sh run.sh
```

It connect to the host but the next commands, the put lines, did not run.

Can I get insights why is that and how can I solve it?

Comment: Don't use `sh` to run Bash scripts. (Your script doesn't contain any Bash-specific syntax, so in this case, it doesn't matter, but you need to understand the difference.)

Comment: Your code should not "not run", but should stall on the `sftp` command, because sftp expects its commands (`put` and so on) from standard input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked interactively because `put` commands were not consumed by shell but running `sftp` process. Script you have attempts to run `put` commands as standalone.

### Redirection

To run `put` you can either feed them to standard input of the `sftp`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sftp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@host <<END
put csv_file
put manifest_file
END
```

where `<<END` denotes take next lines until seeing `END` and redirect them (`<<`) to the standard input of `sftp`.

### Batch File

Or alternatively if you can automate them via batch file called e.g. `batch` and containing simply the put lines:

```
put csv_file
put manifest_file
```

and then tell `sftp` it should process commands in `batch` file like this instead of having shell script:

```
sftp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@host -b batch
```

NOTE: Since you have `bash` shebang in file you can make that file executable by `chmod +x run.sh` and then simply run it as `./run.sh`.